# Access Azure DevOps Secure File properties

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've upload a PKCS#12 certificate [secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=vsts) to my Azure DevOps project, and added the password as a property:

[image: Adding a Secure File]

The problem is that while I can access the certificate file by using a **Download Secure File** task, I can't see any way to access the *properties* of the file?

In the mean-time, I have what I want working by adding the password as a secure **Variable** in a **Variable Group** instead, but I'm still curious as to how to access secure file properties.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what these `Properties` are used for? I'm running into the same question and would love any info you've got.

Comment: @SamHanley nope, and they're pretty much useless without some way to access them! (Note I haven't looked at this for 6 months, so hopefully support/docs for reading these props has actually been implemented now)

Comment: Doesn't seem to have been. Alas!

Comment: 1 year later, and docs still haven't been updated. I've raised it as a GitHub issue to hopefully have it addressed: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8474

Comment: I'm interested too, @AdrianSanguineti. Just went to the GitHub issue you opened. Added my own comment asking for access to the properties as well.

Answer (score -3):

just encrypt the file with a key, then:

1. save the encrypted file in a shared place, for e.g. git repository or storage account, etc.
2. save the key in an Azure key vault or any other vault.
3. during the pipeline, decrypt the file with the key retrieved from AKV.

Comment: people gave thumbs down could give some explanation or share a better solution ?

Comment: Your solution is basically what OP is already doing. They already have an encrypted file in the AzureDevops library/vault and they need to to save the key/password somewhere. OP already found a working alternative using Variable Groups. So they are specifically asking for a way to access the Secure File properties out of pure curiosity. It currently seems to be impossible though.

Comment: @dimizuno, thanks for your clarification. My answer was not clear, in fact, I personnally do not recommend using Azure DevOps library or variables groups, they're some legacy solutions because they're not "AS CODE", very difficult to review, to change, and to maintain. When using azure devops, all the clear texts should be in git, or some storage if for large files, and all the secrets should be keyvault, but not in variable groups. Same thing for the Release pipeline inside Azure DevOps pipeline, it's a GUI solution seems beautiful, but sorry, it's legacy. Above is just my humble opinion.

Comment: @dimizuno, I'm not a fan of the Azure DevOps solution with the secure file feature. For heightened security, all secrets should be stored in a vault, like Azure Key Vault. For large-sized secrets, as I pointed out in my response, we can encrypt these and store the encrypted versions directly in the repo or on shared network storage in plain view. Subsequently, the encryption passphrase can be kept in a vault. The official GitHub Actions documentation recommends the same approach as mine. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#storing-large-secrets